# Chrome not opening google.com, address bar search?

Tags: networking, google-chrome, dns, google-search

I have never experienced anything like this.

Here is what is happening:

- I cannot open `google.com`, not even in incognito mode.
- I can open `google.co.in`
- I cannot search via the address bar in chrome which uses google.com as the search provider.
- I can access all of google's other services like gmail, google drive etc.
- I can open google.com in other browsers like firefox, safari on the same machine
- This also happens with me on chrome on my mobile device.
- I only have the following chrome extensions: adblocker installed along with a git extension called isometric contributions, and a video speed controller, which I have been using since around 4 years.

I have the following chrome flags enabled on my machine (a Macbook pro):

`chrome://flags/#enable-gpu-rasterization`

`chrome://flags/#enable-parallel-downloading`

Every other website, youtube, facebook etc is working properly. I have a 30ms ping, and internet is respectably fast (> 30mbps).

The Optic Fibre cable had broken some days back, which has been repaired, the problem began after the cable has been repaired. My DNS points to google's public DNS `8.8.8.8` as was before cable breakage.

The above only happens intermittently. However today I noticed a severe lag while sshing into an AWS instance. I should also point out that my android device shows Limited Connectivity intermittently when connected to the wifi on the same network (never happened before cable breakage), even though the websites open just fine. However an apple device connected to the same network doesn't show any such warning.

Can anyone please point out/help me diagnose what might be the case.

Comment: Can you try uninstalling chrome and reinstall and changing dns to isp dns or other dns such as cloudfare and check if works ? If it does I will  post as answer

Comment: Sure. Since the behaviour is intermittent, let me try out your suggestion for atleast 24hrs. I will keep the post updated

Comment: @EliteX I did try what you asked me, but it looks that its not a dns problem or browser problem, since it has happened despite a clean install and using cloudflares dns, ISPs dns.There is a 14-15% packet loss happening somewhere in my ISPs internal routers on the way out to US(troubleshot using MTR), just before Google's network territory in US. Why just Google? I guess that might be because of that the frequency of accessing Google is probably more than any other site and hence it is more noticeable, which made me wrongly conclude the scenario. My best guess.

Comment: "There is a 14-15% packet loss happening somewhere in my ISPs internal routers on the way out to US" Then you should be speaking to your ISP.

Comment: @DavidPostill yes called them immediately as soon as I found it out.